# Predicate builder contains

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, contains, predicate

I am trying to execute query through MVC3 with predicate builder. I am getting the error

"Unable to cast the type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types."

I have query passed as below

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchObj.EmployeeIDSortId.ToString()) && SearchObj.EmployeeIDSortId > 0)
    {

        string[] vals =new string[' ']; 
        if (SearchObj.EmployeeIDSortId == 1)
        {
            vals = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k","l" };

        }
        else if (SearchObj.EmployeeIDSortId == 2)
        {

            vals = new string[] { "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s" };

        }
        else if (SearchObj.EmployeeIDSortId == 3)
        {


            vals = new string[] { "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
        }


        employeepredicate =
            employeepredicate.And(emp => emp.EmployeeName.Substring(0, 1).ToLower().Equals(vals.Any()));


         }
```

Can you please suggest what is wrong with this ,I guess it is only due to my query vals.Any().

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me preface - I'm unfamiliar with the `And` method, but the `.Equals(vals.Any())` doesn't look right to me. So, I assume that `And` takes a function returning a bool. What you're really looking for is to find out if the first character in the employee name is contained in the vals array:

`employeepredicate = employeepredicate.And(
         emp => vals.Contains(emp.EmployeeName.Substring(0, 1).ToLower()));`